# PHP how to use openssl_encrypt in a number input

Tags: javascript, php

I'm learning php

I have a form like this

where COD and  KEY are global variables

```
echo' <form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="'.$array['Noart'].'id" value="';
              echo  openssl_encrypt($array['Noart'],COD,KEY)'">;
```

and in another php file, I do this

```
 if(is_numeric(openssl_decrypt($_POST['id'],COD,KEY)))
      {
        $ID=openssl_decrypt($_POST['id'],COD,KEY);
        $msg.="OK ID ".$ID."<br>";
      }else{$msg.="wrong ID ".$ID;}
```

that works fine

but if I try to this is wrong

```
echo'<input style="width:80px;height:30px" class="form-control"
               type="number" name="count" id="'.$array['Noart'].'count" min="1" 
               value=" '.openssl_encrypt(.'';
               echo' '.,COD,KEY).'" max="10" >
```

is there a way to encrypt that value that is changing?

I have searched but can't find how to do it, someone suggested that I use javascript but I didn't know how

I will appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: I have read this twice and I still can't figure out what your problem is. Are there any error codes?

Comment: expected 3 arguments found 0  . 
I guess it's because I can't separate that function like this, using echo, how could I do it then

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149080/how-can-i-update-value-of-input-text-via-ajax